# Is it possible to have a "generic" template parameter in C++, that can be either a non-type template parameter or a type?

Tags: c++, templates

In C++, it's possible to use a type as a template parameter, e.g:

```
template <typename T>
void MyFn();
```

It's also possible to use a non-type as a template parameter in some cases, e.g.:

```
template <int64_t T>
void MyFn2();
```

My question is whether it's possible to have a "generic" template parameter that can be both? Like:

```
template <TypenameOrint64_t T>
void MyFn3();
```

such that both `MyFn3<42>` and `MyFn3<double>` would be acceptable.

An example of how I might use this:

```
template <typename ValType, ValType Head, ValType ...Tail>
struct ListS{

  template <typename OutType, template <ValType ArgType> class Fn>
  using MapHead = ListS<OutType, Fn<Head>::val, Tail...>;
};

template<int64_t N>
struct SquareS{
  static constexpr const int64_t val = N * N;
};

using Sqrd = ListS<int64_t, 3, 4>::MapHead<int64_t, SquareS>;

static_assert(std::is_same<Sqrd, ListS<int64_t, 9, 4>>::value, "Values don't match");
```

The above is a very rough sketch of a compile-time list of values along with a single compile-time "function" on it.  Would it be possible to make something like that also support lists of types, not just lists of non-type template param compatible values, without just duplicating all the code?

Comment: How are you going to use this template parameter if you don't know what it is (type or value)?

Comment: writhe 2 MyFn, one with `typename T` and the other one with the `size_t x`, compile will understand which template to instanciate on each MyFn calls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a “generic” template parameter in C++, that can be either a non-type template parameter or a type?

Short answer: no.

Long answer.

No. The best I can imagine to mix types and values is wrap values in types, using `std::integral_constant`, by example.

So, your desired code, could be written (C++17) almost as follows

```
#include <utility>

template <typename ...>
struct ListS;

template <typename ValType, ValType Head, ValType ...Tail>
struct ListS<std::integral_constant<ValType, Head>,
             std::integral_constant<ValType, Tail>...>
 {
   template <template <auto> class Fn, typename OutType = ValType>
   using MapHead = ListS<std::integral_constant<OutType, Fn<Head>::value>,
                         std::integral_constant<OutType, Tail>...>;
 };

template <auto N>
struct SquareS : public std::integral_constant<decltype(N), N*N>
 { };

int main ()
 {   
   using T1 = ListS<std::integral_constant<long long, 3ll>,
                    std::integral_constant<long long, 4ll>>;
   using T2 = T1::MapHead<SquareS>;
   using T3 = ListS<std::integral_constant<long long, 9ll>,
                    std::integral_constant<long long, 4ll>>;

   static_assert( std::is_same_v<T2, T3> );
 }
```

Pre C++17 you can't use `auto` for the type of the template values so you should make some simple corrections.

Answer (score 2):

You could use function overloading and the `auto` type deduction that came with `C++17`
to accomplish something similar.

```
template<typename myType>
auto myFn3(myType value){
    return value;
}

template<auto value> //takes any non-type parameter
auto myFn3(){
    return value;
}

int main(){
     auto test1_normal = myFn3(3);
     auto test1_cast = myFn3<double>(3); //able to perform a cast
     auto test1_auto = myFn3<3>();
    return 0;
}
```